# If you have fetched a subdomain, what lookup related performance implications are there for accessing another subdomain on the same TLD?

Tags: domain-name-system, performance

Consider this example. My browser visits the following URL:

```
foo.foobar.com
```

The page on the domain creates an iframe for

```
bar.foobar.com
```

Both domains are hosted in AWS Route53 as aliased A records => CloudFront

What performance implications would be experienced in DNS lookup times?

My company is concerned about the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

It'll generate the following:

- Some lookups to find the foobar.com. name server. This depends on what's in the upstream servers caches. Worst case there's three lookups (., com. and foobar.com.)
- DNS Lookup for foo.foobar.com.
- HTTP request for [IP_Foo]
- HTTP response with iframe for bar.foobar.com.]
- DNS Lookup for foo.foobar.com.
- HTTP request for [IP_Bar]
- HTTP response

So there's going to some latency added by the iframe. If everything was hosted on foo.foobar.com, it'd look something like this:

- Some lookups to find the foobar.com. name server. This depends on what's in the upstream servers caches. Worst case there's three lookups (., com. and foobar.com.)
- DNS Lookup for foo.foobar.com
- HTTP request for [IP_Foo]
- HTTP response

The best way I've found to check this is to open the developer console in Google Chrome by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + C`, clicking the Network tab, and then reloading the page. It'll show you how long each element of the page took to load, though it doesn't show DNS requests separately. If you want to see the DNS requests, you can run Wireshark on your test machine to see when the DNS queries goes out.

The effect should be quite minimal though, but you did state that you were interested in the milliseconds.